# Sign google cloud storage blob using access token with POSTMAN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

This is my first post on this website, even if I usually use it to find answers to my issues.

I am using Google cloud storage to store images in a private folder, and I would like to display them in my website.

I saw on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) that I can use signed URLs to achieve my goals.

I am actually using the IAM signBlob method provided by Google to sign a blob using a service account's system-managed private key. When I use the Google API on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob), the POST request is doing great and I receive the keyId and the signedBlob in the response body.

Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce that on Postman or in my own code. The POST request, on POSTMAN, always got a Status 404.

[Screen of the POST requests on POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWo4A.png)

Any advice is welcome, have a nice day,

Sincerely,

Theo.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to my problem by changing the URL directly to :
https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/11483096708985xxxxxxxx:signBlob

It seems that using gRPC Transcoding was a problem on Postman...

Have a good day,

Sincerely

Théo.